# .htaccess redirect specific folder to another URL, ending with the same name

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to do this in .htaccess:

a URL like
http://example.com/folder/different-name
to be redirected to:
http://example.net/different-name

Where at the first site 'folder' is always the same, but 'different-name' is always different

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

RedirectMatch 301 /folder(.*)/ http://example.com/$1